# What is a circle's area if its radius is $\pi$?

Tags: geometry, area

The area of a circle equals $\pi r^2$. If a circle's radius is $\pi$, what is its area? I believe the answer is $\pi^3$, right?

Comment: Yes... the formula doesn't change.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure mathematics.

Comment: Answer will remain the same, as $r$, can be anything, either it may be $\pi$ or $e$

Comment: $r$ can be $\sqrt{\pi}$ and the area will be $\pi^2$.

Comment: right.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: This question hasn't been given enough attention. Someone should put up a bounty!

Comment: Was this so difficult?

Answer (score 3):

Correct.  Given $\ A_\circ(r) = \pi r^2 $, now let $\ r = \pi$. Now $\ A_\circ(\pi) = \pi (\pi)^2 = \pi^3 $.

Comment: And the units will still be of length squared.